# as before request always redirect to login page even for authenticated user

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

Am implementing authentication in yii2 basic project
Login action seems to working fine

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $this->layout = "login-layout"; 
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            var_dump("guest"); die();
        } else {
            var_dump("This is user"); die();
        }   
    }

    $model->password = '';
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I have configured **as before request** in config.php as shown below

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login'],                
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,               
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function () {           
            return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);               
    },
],
```

My problem is *even if user is successfully authenticated still I can't access other pages keep redirecting to the login page* 
Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this after some hours of debugging. The problem was caused by **findIdentity** method in my User model, Since I was creating it to return null as shown below

```
public static function findIdentity($MemberId) {
    $user = self::find();   
     return ;//static($user);
}
```

So I have changed it to

```
public static function findIdentity($MemberId) {
    $user = self::find()->where(['MemberId' => $MemberId])->one();  
     return $user;
}
```

Now, it works fine so the problem was not in **as beforeRequest** instead the application was not finding the actual user.